# how to divide a datetime object by an int

Tags: python, datetime

I can't seem to divide a `datetime.time` object by an `int`.

Looking at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) I can't figure out why it isn't working.

I get the error: `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.time' and 'int'`.

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone, date

time = datetime.strptime("04:23:40", "%H:%M:%S")
print(time)
print(time.time())
time_div = time.time() / 2
print(time_div)>
```

I did see a method that splits the time down into second then performs the division on the number of seconds, but wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: What do you except to get after diving certain `datetime.datetime` instance by integer?

Comment: _"I did see a method"_ - where? _"wondering if there is a better way"_ - "better" how?

Comment: What result would you expect for December 31, 1969?

Comment: @Daweo I would hope to get 02:11:50 as the result

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry saw it a few days ago on a similar past as a comment, I guess what I mean by better would be eliminating the need to do the conversion to seconds and back again. just wondering if what I have shown above is a valid method that I have tried but got the syntax wrong, or if I need to try a different approach?

Comment: It's not a _syntax_ problem, it's a _semantic_ one - dividing a `time` isn't a defined operation. Per the docs you link only `timedelta`s support division. But some context might help understand what that operation means in your case.

Comment: @Sayse, I apologies for my lack of understanding, but where does the date you mentioned come from?

Comment: @ChrisMason - A calendar, how would you divide it by 2? What answer would you expect?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes you are correct I needed to use timedelta. quite new to this so still learning, but thanks for the input

Comment: @Sayse well this is a time so it would be half the time.

Comment: 1.30pm is not half of 3pm... dates and times don't have a concept of division, hours and minutes do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing a (non-existing) `datetime.datetime` method with a `datetime.timedelta` method (see [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)). Timedeltas can be divided. E.g.:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

t = datetime.strptime("04:23:40", "%H:%M:%S")
d = timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second)

print(d/2) # Output: '2:11:50' (type: 'datetime.timedelta')
```

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

What do you expect form dividing date by int?

```
time.timestamp()
```

returns number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970. Maybe datetime.timedelta will help you?